# Pytype can't find python3 interpreter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytype

I'm trying to run `pytype` on a project but I keep getting the error `CRITICAL Could not find a valid python3.5 interpreter in path (found Python 2.7.17)`. However, I have python3 installed. I also have an alias `alias python="python3"`.

- `python -V` - Python 3.6.9
- `python3 -V` - Python 3.6.9
- `python2 -V` - Python 2.7.17

How can I run `pytype`?

Comment: does `python3 -m pytype ....` work?

Comment: @gold_cy nop, gives the exact same error

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when running pytype in a directory with a `setup.cfg` containing `python_version = 3.5`. Temporarily removing `setup.cfg` fixed it for me.